# Mongodb upsert operation seems not atomic which throws DuplicateKeyException

Tags: atomic

I have a mongodb database named 'msgdb', and a collection named 'roster'. The document in 'roster' is like below:

```
{
  "userId": "sn99933289",
  "rosterGroups": [
    {
      "groupId": "242326",
      "groupName": "buddy",
      "rosterItems": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": NumberInt(1)
}
```

I set the field '_id' as the shard key like below:

db.runCommand({ shardcollection: "msgdb.roster", key:{ _id:"hashed" }})

The Java code which calls the upsert method:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

    private void saveRoster(Roster roster) {
        BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(roster, dbObject);
        dbObject.remove("version");
        dbObject.remove("_class");
        Update update = new Update();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : dbObject.entrySet()) {
            update.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        update.inc("version", 1);
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(roster.getUserId());
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, "roster");
    }
```

I found the DuplicateKeyException from the application log. It seems the upsert operation is not atomic. More specific exception stack trace is as below. How to avoid this exception? Any help/hint is appreciated.

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: msgdb.roster index: _id_ dup key: { : "sn88332138" }'; nested exception is com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: msgdb.roster index: _id_ dup key: { : "sn88332138" }'
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:69) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2011) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:463) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doUpdate(MongoTemplate.java:1086) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.upsert(MongoTemplate.java:1052) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.suning.im.server.center.roster.RosterServiceImpl.saveRoster(RosterServiceImpl.java:235) ~[classes:na]
at com.suning.im.server.center.roster.RosterServiceImpl.getRoster(RosterServiceImpl.java:68) ~[classes:na]
at com.suning.im.server.center.roster.RosterServiceImpl.getRosterPresencesWithVirtual(RosterServiceImpl.java:251) ~[classes:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upsert is not atomic. This is insinuated by the Mongo documentation: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/.

> To avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use upsert: true if the query field is uniquely indexed.

So I would recommend using upsert only on fields indexed as unique. If you have multiple fields in the query statement, you could either work with a compound index or hash those fields together (for instance into the id of the document). Luckily you are using a unique index here as you are using the _id field.

Wrapping your upsert in a try catch that issues an update request should solve your problem, as you are sure once in the catch block that the document exists.